# Concurrency programming for parsing a gigabyte file Into one global dictionary

Tags: python-2.7, concurrency, python-multithreading, large-data, concurrentdictionary

I’ve a 2Gig text file. In my program, I read line by line using mmap, and form a ordered-dictionary. It takes almost 40 mins to finish the program. 
I’m thinking about concurrence way here to reduce the timing. 
Program will divide the file into 50 halves by its size. And, pass over chunks of data to each thread at a time. 
And, all parsed chunks by 50 threads will be updating one global dictionary. 
There may repeated data in the chunk, and it’s necessary. 
My concern is, will there be any data loss, or what would be the aftermath for this code.
Provide suggestions or alternative solutions. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Provide some example code and show your research.

Comment: @jdv I’m unable to paste my code in here. It’s basically reading file size in bytes. Dividing it by 50. Start 50 threads for each chunk of data. It’ll call one single func, which will update a global dict.

Comment: Can you explain the “repeated data in the chunk, and it’s necessary” comment? Like you’d have the same key for two different values?

Comment: Exactly the same. Same key for two values. That key can have values from many other threads. That’s why I made it as a global dictionary. I’ve made the global dict accept list as their values. So they’ll just append. No worries on that part. My main worry is about “data loss” or will it work ?

Comment: If you can't put some example code in the question as text, we are limited in the kind of help we can offer. This site works best with a [mcve]

Comment: Which is the fastest way to iterate through a gigabytes sized file? I’m using mmap now. Is there a better way than this?